# Reading parameter passed to the view in the custom tag

Tags: spring, jsp, taglib

If I pass to my view a parameter (from my spring controller), like this:

```
mav.addObject("command", serv.getNewObject());
```

or

```
mav.addObject("command", serv.getObject(id));
```

and in my view I use a custom tag like this:

```
<custom:MainForm action="..." classe="...">
    <custom:FieldBox ordem="...">
        ...
        <custom:Input/>
        ...
    </custom:Fieldbox>
</custom:MainForm>
```

how I could access this parameter `command` inside the custom tag? I try this, but I am getting a null value:

```
Object object = pageContext.getAttribute("command");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ModelAndView` attributes (and eventually a basic Map) are stored based on the information, by default it is `request scoped`

So go for -

```
Object object = pageContext.getRequest().getAttribute("command");
```

Or if you want to find the attribute present in any of scope ,then try-

```
Object object =  pageContext.findAttribute("command");//will search for attribute in all scope page,request and session
```